# Failed to link org/apache/myfaces/taglib/core/VerbatimTag

Tags: jsf, myfaces, jboss-eap-7

I have updated myfaces from 2.0.18 to 3.0.2

After that I've got following error when I want to start JBOSS EAP 7.1 server:

> [2023-10-11 03:03:25,907] Artifact TestNumberEAR-2.0.7-SNAPSHOT.ear: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.

> [2023-10-11 03:03:25,907] Artifact TestNumberEAR-2.0.7-SNAPSHOT.ear: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit."TestNumberEAR-2.0.7-SNAPSHOT.ear"."TestNumberGenerator.war".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "TestNumberGenerator.war" of deployment "TestNumberEAR-2.0.7-SNAPSHOT.ear"
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/apache/myfaces/taglib/core/VerbatimTag (Module "deployment.TestNumberEAR-2.0.7-SNAPSHOT.ear.TestNumberGenerator.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/apache/myfaces/shared/taglib/UIComponentELTagBase (Module "deployment.TestNumberEAR-2.0.7-SNAPSHOT.ear.TestNumberGenerator.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link jakarta/faces/webapp/UIComponentELTag (Module "deployment.TestNumberEAR-2.0.7-SNAPSHOT.ear.TestNumberGenerator.war" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.subunit."TestNumberEAR-2.0.7-SNAPSHOT.ear"."TestNumberGenerator.war".deploymentCompleteService"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit."TestNumberEAR-2.0.7-SNAPSHOT.ear".deploymentCompleteService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit."TestNumberEAR-2.0.7-SNAPSHOT.ear"."TestNumberGenerator.war".deploymentCompleteService]"]}

And here is my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core.internal</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl-shared</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false"
         version="5.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Any idea what the problem here could be?

Comment: You should have upgraded the server instead of pom.xml. All dependencies are wrong for EAP7 except for `jakarta.jakartaee-api`. Remove them all to avoid getting confused yourself by seeing code to compile successfully while it won't at all run at the target runtime.

Comment: Thanks for replying, what are the supported JBOSS EAP servers for this myfaces 3.0 and servlet 5.0 ?

Comment: That's going to be EAP 8 which supports EE10 including Faces 4 and Servlet 6: https://access.redhat.com/articles/113373 Note thus that they chose to skip EE9 (waste of effort because it's basically identical to EE8 with only the javax renamed to jakarta), so you can upgrade further to Faces 4 / Servlet 6 right away to get more goodies.

Comment: We are using JBOSS EAP 7.1 and no plans to upgrade to JBOSS EAP 8 as of now. 
But to upgrade myfaces to 3.0, it seems servlet 5.0 is required which means EAP 8 is required(it supports servlet 6.0 & myfaces 4.0) and it won't work with EAP 7.x. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @BalusC, can you please confirm on my above understanding.